# Optional Binding (String: AnyObject) to [String]

Tags: swift, afnetworking, conditional-binding

I have a JSON object/dictionary I retrieved from `AFNetworking` and I want to conditionally unwrap the key into an array of strings.

```
var person: [String : AnyObject] = ...

if let interests = person["interests"] as [String]{
   // Do something
}
```

I get the following error message: `(String : AnyObject) is not convertible to [String]`. I don't think I can typecast `person` to `[String : Any]` because it comes out as `[String : AnyObject]` from the `AFNetworking` framework. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not telling the truth. No one can reproduce based on what you've shown. Show your _real_ code. Do not type by hand: copy and paste so that we see _exactly_ what you are saying.

Comment: @matt. You can easily reproduce the code. I've written basically exactly what i posted in `Playground` and took a screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/2aSAjRe.png

Comment: Because you didn't import UIKit. See my screenshot which trumps your screenshot!

Comment: @matt I want to solve this issue just as much as anyone else, I'm still getting a compile error: http://i.imgur.com/gu9wtHe.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your Xcode.  You are using an old version.  Prior to Xcode 6.1, `String` was not considered an object type: you had to use `NSString` instead:

```
if let interests = person["interests"] as? [NSString] {
```

Apple fixed that issue, so this now works with Xcode 6.1:

```
if let interests = person["interests"] as? [String] {
```

Since Swift is rapidly evolving, you are advised to keep up to date with the latest released verison of Xcode, which as of this writing is Xcode 6.1.1.